# How does the identity element change when a set is multiplied by a scalar?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider the sets
$$A = \{1, a_2, a_3,\ldots ,a_{\phi(n)}\}$$
and
$$B = \{c, ca_2, ca_3,\ldots ,ca_{\phi(n)}\}$$

where $\gcd(a_i,n) = \gcd(c,n)=1$, so $c\in A,B$.

---

Easy to see that the set $A$ forms a group under multiplication $\mod n$, and the set $B$ forms a group under multiplication $\mod cn$.

I'm wondering if there is a formula to predict the identity element of group $B$ with out constructing the cayley table. For example, when $n=8$ and $c=5$, we have $25=5^2=c^2$ as the identity element of $B$. Would this work in general ? If so, is there any nice way to understand why/how $c^2$ is the identity element of group $B$ ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are denoting by $1=a_1, a_2,\dots,a_{\phi(n)}$ the integers  in $[0,n-1]$ that are coprime to $n$. If you consider
$$
B'=\{ca_1\bmod n,ca_2\bmod n,\dots,ca_{\phi(n)}\bmod n\}
$$
then $B'=A$ (just the order is different), and the identity of this group is obviously $1$: the corresponding element in $B$ is $ca_i$, where
$$
ca_i\equiv 1\pmod{n}
$$
(the inverse of $c$ modulo $n$), which can be determined with the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Very nice, I think I get your method. Thank you (: Don't you mean the corresponding element in $B$ is $\color{red}{ca_i}$, where $$ca_i\equiv 1\pmod{n}$$ ?

Comment: @Hiiii Yes, sorry for the misprint.