# I have a doubt regarding the group {4,8,12,16}under multiplication modulo 20.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I faced a question show that {4,8,12,16} is a group under multiplication mod 20.It is fine.I have solved the problem also.But I am feeling something strange in it.The idenity element of multiplication modulo 20 should be 1 which is not in the group.I mean does the identity element change it I change the set I am dealing with keeping the binary operation same.Please give me a similiar example in which identity element under the same operation changes due to changing the set in a group.

Comment: Funny, I thought the identity element of a group was something satisfying $e*g=g*e=g$ for all $g$, not something with the label "$1$".

Comment: Build a cayley table?

Comment: I have built Cayley table.

Comment: It appears the identity element is 16 since $16×_{20}g=g×_{20}16=g$. One part of the definition is *identity:* There exists an element $e$ such that $e×g=g×e=g$ for all $g\in G$. Well there it is... $e=16$. The number $1$ is not in the set so can't be considered.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a more advanced way of looking at this. Right now, this may not be at the right level for the OP - building the Cayley table is probably the right way to go for the OP - but it provides insight into what is actually going on.

Look at the ring ${\mathbb Z}/20$.
This is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}/4 \times {\mathbb Z}/5$;
the isomorphism from the latter to the former is given by $(x,y) \mapsto 5x - 4y$.

Now look at all elements of ${\mathbb Z}/4 \times {\mathbb Z}/5$ of the form $(0,x)$
with $x \in {\mathbb Z}/5^*$, i.e., at $\{0\} \times {\mathbb Z}/5^*$. Because $0^2=0$,
this forms a group under multiplication even though $0$ is not invertible in ${\mathbb Z}/4$.

The elements $(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)$ of ${\mathbb Z}/4 \times {\mathbb Z}/5$ correspond to
$-4=16$, $-8=8$, $-12=4$, $-16=4$ of ${\mathbb Z}/20$, so that is exactly the OP's example. The unit element is $(0,1)$ in $\{0\} \times {\mathbb Z}/5^*$, corresponding to $16$ in ${\mathbb Z}/20$.

This provides a way to construct many more examples. For example,
using ${\mathbb Z}/2 \times {\mathbb Z}/3 \cong {\mathbb Z}/6$ via $(x,y) \mapsto 3x - 2y$, the same
construction gives the multiplicative group $\{0\} \times {\mathbb Z}/3^*$.
The elements $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ of this group correspond to $4$ and $2$
of ${\mathbb Z}/6$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $S=\{4,8,12,16\}$

The identity element of algebraic structure $(S,\times_{20})$ is $16$.

[image]

- Is this group closed under modulo multiplication: YES
- Is the operation associative: $(4\times_{20}8)\times_{20}12=12\times_{20}12=\textbf{4}=4\times_{20}(8\times_{20}12)=4\times_{20}16=\bf{4}$
- Is there exists identity : YES (16)
- Does each element has its own inverse : YES ($4 = 4^{-1}, 8 = 12^{-1}, 12= 8^{-1}, 16 = 16^{-1}$)

So, this algebraic structure is indeed a **group** under multiplication modulo 20.

Comment: This does not address the OP’s doubt.

Comment: But how is it possible that 16 is idenity element with respect to multiplication modulo 20 because 1 is an idenity w r t the same operation.

Comment: @CarstenS Yes, it does not.. But I think OP somehow got confused with $1$ as identity.

Comment: Not actually,I am the OP.I know the identity element is 16.But it is somewhat strange because the operation multipliction modulo 20 has idenity 1 when operated on U(20) but has identity 16 when operated on {4,8,12,16}.It mean that identity depends not only on the operation but also on the underlying set.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar but $1$ is not an element in your set.

Comment: That is what I am saying.Can someone give me a binary operation that operates on 2 sets S1 and S2 but has 2 different identitites on the 2 sets.

Comment: I want an example of a binary operation on two sets S1 and S2 where S1 and S2 are subsets of a set S such that when the operation is carried on S1 then it has idenity e1 and when operates on S2 it has identity e2 and e1 not equal to e2.And it is not necessary that the operation should be closed and well defined on S also.But the opearation should separately be close and well defined on S1 and on S2.

Comment: 1 is not in the set.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Check this  [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238460/how-does-the-identity-element-change-when-a-set-is-multiplied-by-a-scalar might help

Comment: Are there some more such sites.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar sites or sets ?

Comment: sites on internet.

Comment: Where can I find more detailed discussion on multiplication of a group by a scalar that changes its idenity element.

Comment: Vineet are you answering?

Comment: I didn't find any such links. I think you should either rephrase the question or ask a fresh one " multiplication of a group by a scalar that changes its identity element."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94841/discussion-between-kishalay-sarkar-and-vineet).

Comment: You can mail me on kishalaysarkar2000@gmail.com whenever you find any new detail on this question or want to discuss on this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simpler example look at $\{2,4\}$ modulo $6$; and a similar one $\{3,6,9,12\}$ modulo $15$. Also $\{7, 14\}$ or $\{3,6,9,12,15,18\}$ modulo $21$.

Take the last one, for example. Every element is divisible by $3$ but not by $7$. Their products will therefore be divisible by $3$ but not by $7$, and reducing $\bmod 21$ does not change divisibly by $3$ or $7$.

The set in fact comprises a complete set of non-zero residues modulo $7$. Since the products are all divisible by $3$, the value of he product modulo $21$ depends only on the value modulo $7$. The multiplicative identity is $15\equiv 1 \bmod 7$.

In your modulo $20$ example, if you reduce the elements modulo $5$ you get $\{4,3,2,1\}$ and the identity element gets the name you expect.

Note that the identity element of a group is defined by its properties, not its name.

---

You ask in your comments how your set is a subgroup - but you don't indicate what you think it is a subgroup of. But note that the non-zero integers modulo $20$ do not form a group under multiplication - we have $4\times 5=0$ for example, so the set is not closed under the proposed binary operation. You have to exclude multiples of $2$ and $5$ to get the standard group of invertible elements, but this does not contain the elements you are considering. No subgroup.

---

In the case where multiplication does not form a group we can have both non-trivial nilpotent $(e^2=0, e\neq 0)$ and idempotent $(e^2=e, e\neq 0,1)$ elements. Idempotents are candidates for the identity in groups made up of a subset of the original elements.

Modulo $20$ for example, $5$ is idempotent. Can you find a non-trivial multiplicative group modulo $20$ with $5$ as the identity?

Comment: I did not understand the last paragraph of your answer.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar (With the operation of multiplication, the non-zero multiples of $4$ are not a subgroup of the non-zero residues modulo $20$. One reason is because the non-zero residues modulo $20$ do not form a group with this operation (if it were a group it would have $19$ elements and no non-trivial subgroups). I've added a little more o the answer.