# Same binary operator gives multiple identities on different subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Give me an example of a binary operation on two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of a set $S$ such that when the operation is carried on $S_1$ then it has identity $e_1$ and when operates on $S_2$ it has identity $e_2$ and $e_1$ not equal to $e_2$. And it is not necessary that the operation should be closed and well defined on $S$ also, but the operation should separately be close and well defined on $S_1$ and on $S_2$.

The operation multiplication modulo 20 $(\times_{20})$ has identity $1$ when operated on $U(20)$ but has identity $16$ when operated on set 
$\{4,8,12,16 \} $.

Are there any more such examples. I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238460/how-does-the-identity-element-change-when-a-set-is-multiplied-by-a-scalar).

Comment: This is a followup question from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260615/i-have-a-doubt-regarding-the-group-4-8-12-16under-multiplication-modulo-20)

Answer (score 1):

You can make many examples by considering multiplication on $\Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n$ for integers $m, n\geq 2$. Then the monoid $S_1 = \Bbb Z_m\times \{0\}\setminus(0,0)$ has identity element $(1, 0)$ and the monoid $S_2 = \{0\}\times \Bbb Z_n\setminus(0,0)$ has identity $(0,1)$.

If $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, then $\Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{mn}$, and $S_1$ becomes all (non-zero) multiples of $n$ and $S_m$ becomes all (non-zero) multiples of $m$. This is what happened in your example, with $m = 5, n = 4$.

Feel free to extend these examples to $\Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n\times G$ for any $G$ with a binary operation with an idempotent element $g$ (i.e. $g^2 = g$), with the corresponding identities becoming $(1,0,g)$ and $(0,1,g)$.